# Bayesian alternative for Jennrich test

Tags: bayesian, chi-squared-test

I have two correlation matrices, and I try to figure out whether they are significantly different. For that, I used Jennrich test (as described here: https://personality-project.org/r/html/cortest.mat.html) and found no evidence for significant difference. I'm wondering if there's a Bayesian test or any other way to actually test check evidence for null hypothesis.